# Returning narrowed down SELECT based on associated table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a join query I use to pull data from another table:

```
SELECT [THEME].[NAME], 
       [THEMETYPE].[TYPE] 
FROM   [THEME] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [THEMETYPE] 
                    ON [THEME].[THEMETYPEID] = [THEMETYPE].[PK_THEMETYPE] 
WHERE  COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%' 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN [THEMETYPE].[TYPE] IS NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END, 
          [THEMETYPE].[TYPE]
```

I need to add the ability to narrow it down if a 3rd tables values match up:

```
Where producttheme.productid = variable-paramater-here 
AND producttheme.themeid = theme.pk_theme
```

Here is a pic of the table:

[image]

So if the 1 is chosen above, it will return all [Theme].[Name] and the associated [ThemeType].[Type] where The ThemeId is associated with ProductId = 1

Edit: to be more clear ThemeId is the Primary key in the Theme table where Theme.Name exists.

Comment: Can you join across to the third table, and write your `on` accordingly? Or is it more complex than that?

Comment: How would I approach joining the 3rd table?

Comment: You can have multiple JOIN statements in a single SQL query. Have a quick read up on joins at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213233(v=sql.80).aspx, and also take a look at the answers that have appeared since my original comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would give you some idea, please adjust the column names accordingly:

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme] 
Left Outer Join [ThemeType] 
ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
join ProductTheme PT
on  PT.ProductID=ThemeType.ProductID
WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID = VARIABLE-PARAMATER-HERE AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme
ORDER BY [ThemeType].[Type]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether or not you need the `WHERE` condition before you add the 3rd table, you can try one of these 2 options:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE1 T1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
                    ON T1.FIELDA = T2.FIELDA 
       INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 
               ON T1.FIELDA = T3.FIELDA 
WHERE  T1.FIELDB = 'aaa' 
       AND T3.FIELDC = 12
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT T1.FIELDA, 
               T2.FIELDB 
        FROM   TABLE1 T1 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
                            ON T1.FIELDA = T2.FIELDA 
        WHERE  T1.FIELDC = 'aaa')T3 
       INNER JOIN TABLE3 T4 
               ON T3.FIELDA = T3.FIELDA 
                  AND T4.FIELDC = 12
```

I hope this gives you something to work with.

If you provide some sample data, I can set up a working example.